# What is a better treatment combinet with omega 3 , for improoving studying performance and reducing anxiety?

Tags: natural-remedy, stress, anxiety-disorders, omega-3, subconscious-stress

I'm using omega 3 currently and I want to add another supplement.

I'm thinking about using another supplement and undecided between Ashwagandha and Rhodiola Rosea .

This webpage shows that ashwaganda is better for my cause (compared to Rhadiola Rosea , which is used to relieve fatigue and deppression and to improve general cognition and subjective well being.)

Ashwaganda: https://examine.com/supplements/ashwagandha/
Rhadiola rosea: https://examine.com/supplements/rhodiola-rosea/

Meanwhile in the webpage drugs.com there is more evidence regarding to the effects I want to achieve

R.R: https://www.drugs.com/npp/rhodiola-rosea.html
A. : https://www.drugs.com/npp/ashwagandha.html

I will read further in the references to get a better understanding of the mechanisms of each plant, although I believe Ashwaganda is better .

Any comment and suggestion is well welcomed.

P.s: I want to stay away from synthetic medication as much as possible and I don't believe my neurologist is this much well informed to help me in the choice (I think it would be easier for him to give Adaptol as he has done before)

Thank you in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general concentration issues can be related to any lack of vitamins. 
E.g. you may supplement Vitamin B12 contained in Spirulina or chlorella algae.

Another Thing which can remarkably encourage your Brain capacity is curcuma. Combine it with pepper and add it into smoothies or eat it as a whole. A little portion of virgine plant oil may also increase the effect of curcuma.

You need to understand, that anxiety is triggered by a fight-or-flight mechanism thats inside us.

To reduce anxiety, there are several things to do which all lower your anxiety.

- sleep at least 8 hours a night
- Eat something when you wake up (Your body may cause stress because of a low blood sugar)
- Take walks into nature. Really enjoy it!
- Meditation, especially breath control
- generally Eating healthy

Comment: Hello and welcome to Health! Great to see new faces. Because one’s health is such an important issue, we require that all answers are backed up by evidence so that anyone can asses the merit of the answer. [Here is a guide](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784/8212) that will direct you to reliable references.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Thanks I'll do my best.